# Has Angela Merkel criticised travel bans on Israelis?

Tags: israel, germany, angela-merkel

A subset of [Are any of the notable critics of Trumps immigration ban on record as criticizing Iran's etc... ban on anyone connected to Israel?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/14964/are-any-of-the-notable-critics-of-trumps-immigration-ban-on-record-as-criticizin)

Has Angela Merkel, who has criticised Trump's travel bans on seven Muslim-majority countries, criticised bans by Iran, and/or other countries, of travel by Israelis? If not, has she or those working for her stated why not?

Comment: Note that Merkel specifically critizised Trump for failing to accept war refugees.  Very few Israelies apply for status as a refugee from war.

Comment: Critically, Israel's state of hostility with surrounding Muslim countries basically predates Israel as a recognised nation. The year Israel officially banned Israeli citizens from visiting Muslim nations without special permission is [1954](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israeli_passport#Limitations_on_use_by_Israel), the year [Angela Merkel was *born*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Angela_Merkel). I can't find when Iran officially banned Israel, but it is likely to be *before* Merkel took office; whereas this is an actual action affecting German citizens this weekend.

Comment: No, not that I can find but it's quite a different situation. Imagine if trump had banned everyone from those countries AND also banned Americans from travelling to said countries AND those countries had also banned any Americans. I find it weird that Israel has banned it's citizens from travel to certain countries.

Answer (score 19):

I don't know if she has ever specifically criticized Iran on its ban of Israelis traveling to Iran, but she has on multiple occasions made statements like "[Iran must recognize Israel's existence](http://www.dw.com/en/merkel-iran-must-recognize-israels-existence/av-19052536)" and "[Iran's stance on israel is unacceptable](http://www.timesofisrael.com/merkel-irans-stance-on-israel-unacceptable/)". Given that, I think we can safely assume that her view on Iran's travel restrictions would be critical.

Comment: No, we cannot safely assume what seems to be a convinient guess without any evidence to back it up.

Comment: @user4012 The evidence is a clear and present pattern without any counter-evidence I can find. I agree its a guess, but I think its a educated and safe guess. If you can find evidence to the contrary I will happily amend my answer.

Comment: Evidence is taht when she feels strongly about travel bans, she speaks out about travel bans. Explicitly. Additionally, this isn't just Iran, whereas her comments were Iran only, which actually acts as evidence against your guess.

Comment: That's not evidence.... If you find something you can cite we can talk.